# How to remove multiple attributes from a node?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I have this image element:

```
<img class="cat" src="img/tom.png" alt="Cat">
```

I want to remove both `src` and `alt` attributes at once.
I expected [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) method to take multiple arguments, but it doesn't.

Is there another way to do so other than this repetitive code:

```
image.removeAttribute('src');
image.removeAttribute('alt');
```

Comment: You could set its `outerHTML`, but it would really be best simply to call `removeAttribute` twice, or create your own helper function that accepts multiple arguments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make a function that takes an element and attributes you want to remove.

```js
function removeAttributes(element, ...attrs) {
  attrs.forEach(attr => element.removeAttribute(attr))
}

removeAttributes(document.querySelector('img'), 'src', 'alt')
```

```html
<img class="cat" src="img/tom.png" alt="Cat">
```

If you want to call it on DOM element you could extend Element prototype.

```js
Element.prototype.removeAttributes = function(...attrs) {
  attrs.forEach(attr => this.removeAttribute(attr))
}

document.querySelector('img').removeAttributes('src', 'alt')
```

```html
<img class="cat" src="img/tom.png" alt="Cat">
```

Comment: For the record, mutating the built-in objects is *very* bad practice.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure it makes it any better but you could probably do something like this:

```
['alt', 'src'].forEach(attribute => image.removeAttribute(attribute));
```

or create a general remove attributes function:

```
const removeAttributes = (element, ...attributes) => attributes.forEach(attribute => element.removeAttribute(attribute));
```

which you would call like this:

```
removeAttributes(image, 'alt', 'src');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery solution:** space separated attributes like `image.removeAttr('src alt')` should work.

**Edit:** using pure Javascript you can loop through an array using removeAttribute:

Comment: This is jQuery.
I'm looking for a JavaScript-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it --

```
(() => {
        'use strict';
        let token = 'src|alt';
        if (token === '' || token === '{{1}}') { return; }
        let tokens = token.split(/\s*\|\s*/);
        let selector = 'img';
        if (selector === '' || selector === 'img') {
            selector = `[${tokens.join('],[')}]`;
        }
        let rmattr = () => {
            let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            for ( let element of elements ) {
                for (let attr of tokens) {
                        element.removeAttribute(attr);
                }   
            }      
        };
        if (document.readyState === 'loading' || document.readyState === 'interactive' || document.readyState === 'complete') {
                 rmattr();
        } else {
                 addEventListener('load', rmattr);
        }
})();
```

Comment: I think your code will allways return on line 4 because you are checking `token` against "src|alt" which you assigned to `token` on line 3.

Comment: `===` means `token` has to be a string and its content has to be `''` or `'src|alt'`.